# Difference between AsyncPostBackTrigger and PostBackTrigger on UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView`(ucLAD) in my `UpdatePanel`(upnlListing). Inside my `ucLAD` I have a checkbox and an action for `rowClicked`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlListing" runat="server" >
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucLAD"/>
        <%-- <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ucLAD"/> --%>
     </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlRequest" runat="server" style="margin-top:15px; height: auto;">
             <ucgv:BaseGrid runat="server" ID="ucLAD"/>
        </asp:Panel>

     </ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I use the `PostBackTrigger` the action performed would be the `rowClicked` same thing happen when I check the checkbox but when I use the `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, I can check the checkboxes but when I click the row, the action for `rowClicked` don't trigger. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As describe in on of the SO question

[What is the difference between AsyncPostBackTrigger & PostBackTrigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912614/what-is-the-difference-between-asyncpostbacktrigger-postbacktrigger)

Controls inside an UpdatePanel by default cause a partial page update, controls outside cause a postback, using these triggers it is possible to change this behaviour as required.

From http://seminaarit.codezone.fi/video/devdays-2007/track1/2/2-ASP-dotNET_AJAX_Extensions.ppt

### AsyncPostBackTrigger

Converts postbacks into async callbacks
Typically used to trigger updates when controls outside an UpdatePanel post back
If ChildrenAsTriggers="false", can be used to specify which controls inside UpdatePanel should call back rather than post back

### PostBackTrigger

Lets controls inside UpdatePanel post back
Typically used to allow certain controls to post back when ChildrenAsTriggers="true

Comment: Sorry but the question here is specific to my problem. There are different results from these different methods. Kindly elaborate your answer. What am I going to do with my codes? What are the specific modifications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912614/what-is-the-different-between-asyncpostbacktrigger-postbacktrigger-really?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical explain for AsyncPostBackTrigger and PostBackTrigger above is absolutely Correct.
Here I gave You example for those two:

```
<td style="padding-left: 8px;">
     <asp:UpdatePanel  runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RBtn_InventoryPriceWithPurchase" Text="Inventory Price With Purchase" GroupName="ReportAnalysis" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RBtn_InventoryPriceWithPurchase_CheckedChanged"/>
         </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RBtn_InventoryPriceWithPurchase"EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
          </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>

<td style="padding-left: 8px;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Always">
     <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="RBtn_MerchandisingReport" Text="Merchandising Report" GroupName="ReportAnalysis" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RBtn_MerchandisingReport_CheckedChanged" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="RBtn_MerchandisingReport"/>
 /Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```