# UpdatePanel with trigger not working in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

My code is like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAssessments" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtAssessmentsNotes" Height="100" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mgntop mgnbtm align-center">

                    <asp:Button ID="btnAssessments" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnAssessments_OnClick" Text="Update Assessments" />
                </div>

            </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers> 
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAssessments" runat="server" EventName="Click"/>
                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void btnAssessments_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }
```

And When I click on `btnAssessments` click event is not firing. Does any one have any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN's [description of AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> For controls that are inside a panel when the ChildrenAsTriggers property is false.

Default of `ChildrenAsTriggers` is `true`, so this is not your case. For controls inside the UpdatePanel you can use `PostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAssessments" runat="server" />
```

For the difference between the two you can check out other SO questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330089/difference-between-asyncpostbacktrigger-and-postbacktrigger-on-updatepanel).